# iPhone AddressBook Timestamps?

Tags: iphone, addressbook

I want to know when certain Contacts haven been updated or created. Or at least to know when the Addressbook has been updated the last time.

Does the Addressbook provide timestamps or is there some workaround?

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every address book record has a [modified timestamp](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABRecordRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001536-CH3g-BAJEEJBA).